# Old laptop having blinking issue on screen after several parts getting changed

Tags: laptop, display, flex

My dad has an old Acer Aspire 4732z, nothing special of a laptop but still works and is good for what he requires. A couple of months ago he told me if I could check it because it started blinking and he was unable to see the screen.

I checked it and at first I thought about doing some extra stuff to give it a few more years of useful life, so I've basically done the following:

- Bought new bottom casing (where all the hardware stuff goes) old one was pretty spent, discolored and brittle
- Bought a new LCD, thought the problem was there
- Bought a 1TB SSD as an upgrade, used to have a regular 1TB HDD
- Bought a new battery, old one was dead

One day I started cleaning it up and readjusting everything, and after assembling everything, the exact same issue persisted.

So, my next thought was to change the flex cable, ordered one (at the moment not sure if new or refurbished), but that didn't solve the issue either. I tried installing it carefully and without forcing it.

I was out of my level of expertise at that point, so I took it with a guy that I thought could fix it. At first he told me that the flex cable was the issue and that something was not right with the flex cable positioning or installation. Just in case I took my time in going back for the laptop and when I got there, the issue was exactly the same, he basically wasn't able to fix it.

He told me apparently the bezel/case/hinge assembly was in some way doubled and that's what causing the issue, but since the top closes perfectly in line with the rest of the laptop I am not sure this is the problem.

Since I've already invested quite more than the current laptop's value I don't want to surrender now, but I don't want to buy another flex cable and that not being the solution.

I am also looking for a new bezel/case/hinge assembly, but so far I've only found the bezel and the hinges (very expensive on their own), but I am not convinced this is the issue.

The other reason why I'm a little stubborn about this is that I wanted to surprise my dad with the renewal of the laptop and the main thing is that the computer works fine except for the blinking screen. I installed Windows 10 and it works fine with the SSD... but that bliking makes it unusable.

Sometimes it can stay okay for a couple of minutes, then it starts blinking and goes back to normal and then it would be blinking for a few minutes, then it can stay completely white for a couple of minutes. Cooling/temperature doesn't seem to be related since I leave it off for a few hours and turn it on again and sometimes it even boots with white screen.

I think I can run it with an external display, haven't been able to check because I no longer have VGA screens and I don't want to buy an adapter just for that.

I know the computer could be used stationary with an external screen, but that defeats the purpose of the entire fix.

Should I look for another flex cable or is the issue elsewhere?

**UPDATE**

I got a VGA-to-HDMI adapter and the external screen works. It has some noise issues but I think that's either from the adapter or the VGA interface, otherwise no blinking.

So from here on, should I look for another flex cable? Or what's the issue?

**UPDATE 2023 June**

So I know it's been a long time, but I had it catching dust and recently decided to try at it again.

I changed the flex cable with a new one, and the result was the same.

My last resort is to change the motherboard, I found the [same model on AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004216844843.html), but I am not sure that would work.

My theory is that maybe the processor is having age-related heating issues because if the laptop has been idle for a while the screen works fine for some time and then it starts blinking again and goes white in the end. From what I see the new motherboard comes with no processor.

So after checking the CPU of the laptop [is this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32870396086.html) ...which is actually a decent price... so in theory if I buy the mobo and CPU it would be an entirely new PC except for some casing and the keyboard.

Do you consider this would solve the blinking? I honestly don't know what else could be the case.

Comment: Did you replace the backlight?  I read this but could not see that you replaced this.

Comment: @John I also thought about the backlight, or more specifically about the CCFL inverter at first, but he said the screen blinks white, not black. I would guess this is a graphics card issue.

Comment: Next thing I would test is video-out to rule out a graphics card issue. You can get a VGA-HDMI or VGA-DVI adapter for around 10 bucks if you do not have a compatible screen.

Comment: Could be either.  Graphics in a Laptop will be a GPU and might require replacing the board

Comment: I changed the entire LCD screen, so that's discarded. The GPU could be the issue. I am going to get one of those adapters, I wanted to avoid it, but it would seem it's necessary to find out what's causing the issue. So you're saying that if it's the GPU I should get a new mobo for the laptop? Any idea where I could find a new one?

Comment: So you are saying that the guy who tried to fix it is inventing stuff :) just to be clear lol

Comment: Put the exact model description into eBay and see if you get a properly returnable replacement.

Comment: I use the exact model as search word "4732z". What I get 95% of the time is either LCD replacements, batteries, chargers or keyboards. Ocasionally I get other parts like flex cable, some plastic parts and that's basically it. I am not sure if there's a specialized site for this or ebays is my only option. It's a basic laptop so there should be a bunch of parts available even if it's old.

Comment: I ordered the VGA adapter to check if it works with a screen. If it does, any recommendations on what to do next?

Comment: Have you checked for a possible *software* or *OS* Issue? Try running from a live USB, e.g., WinPE (AKA Win RE" or Ubuntu Live USB. These can be made for free, can be tested in 5 minutes without installation, an, if the PC runs from USB without issue, you've been fixing the wrong thing.

Comment: I swapped hard disks and installed a new operating system. The issue starts on POST not while in Windows, so I don't think it's software related. I am expecting the adapter to come in a couple of days and I'll update my question.

Comment: I updated the question. External screen works without blinking. Is another flex cable a possible solution?

Comment: Any recommendations @mashuptwice

Comment: @MihailMinkov you've already changed the cable and the issue persists. I suspect a cold solder joint. I'd use some (electronics rated) ice spray and try to provoke the white screen with that. (Do not use both short after each other, as ice spray is usually combustible!) Also try flexing the board. Some DIY reflowing could save it, but could also kill it completely. But seriously, this is a over 10 years old machine, for the price of the parts (I guess 120-180€) you've already thrown in, you could've gotten a nice used thinkpad with way nicer specs and no issues at all.

Comment: Before proceeding you might want to share a video of the "blinking".

Comment: But what solder problem? Upon connecting the video card to an external monitor there's no external blinking. The main display is the one still blinking. I am going to show a video tomorrow.

Comment: @mashuptwice I updated the original question. Would a new mobo+CPU fix this issue? They are not that expensive.